# Does Pulp library have a limit of variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pulp

Does anyone know if pulp library has a limit of variables? And if it does, how many variables can I use in it.

Comment: It seems unlikely, although performance is probably dependent on the number of variables -- too many variables and it might take a long time to calculate the solution.

Comment: thanks, I was using AMPL for students before, and it has a limit of variables in the free trial. Since pulp is free, I thought it may has a limit, but didn't find anything in the documentation.